# TS18003 error with tsconfig.json inheritance in lerna monorepo

Tags: node.js, typescript, inheritance, tsconfig, lerna

I have a monorepo using lerna as the repo manager and multiple packages with `tsconfig.json` files. I'd like to have a custom base `tsconfig.json` file and other ones to inherit from the base one. Upon running `tsc` in a project with a `tsconfig.json` file inheriting from the base one, I receive the following error message:

```
error TS18003: No inputs were found in config file '[...]/packages/core/tsconfig.json'. Specified 'include' paths were '["../tsconfig/src/"]' and 'exclude' paths were '[]'.
```

The include path should actually be `./src` (which would resolve to `[...]/packages/core/src`) in the inheriting `tsconfig.json` and not `../tsconfig/src/`.

I'm aware of the fact that inheritance will overwrite keys instead of merging, which in fact is not the problem here. I already tried setting the properties `rootUrl` and `baseUrl` and realized afterwards the `include` property is not affected by them.

What am I missing?

Below are my `tsconfig.json` files:

---

`packages/tsconfig/tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
    "extends": "@sindresorhus/tsconfig",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "dist",
    },
    "include": [
        "src/",
    ]
}
```

`packages/core/tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "extends": "tsconfig"
    // This is where the include array should appear upon inheriting
    // without the path getting transformed to ../tsconfig/src/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest trying to change configuration in `packages/core/tsconfig.json` like this:

```
{
    "extends": "../tsconfig/tsconfig",
}
```